# How does nodes list get built up in __repr__(self) method while invoking other methods in class LinkedList

Tags: python-3.x, repr

I'm trying to understand how the `__repr__` method gets called and the nodes list gets updated during invocation of class's other methods.  Sorry if my terminology isn't correct. I've only included the prepend and append methods for brevity. It looks to me like the list "nodes" would get initialized over and over again. Thanks!

```
class Node:
    
    """A node in a singly-linked list"""
    
    def __init__(self, dataval=None, nextval=None):
        self.dataval = dataval
        self.nextval = nextval
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return repr(self.dataval)
```

```
class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        
        """Creating a new singly-linked list."""
        
        self.head = None
        
    def __repr__(self):
        
        """Creating a string representation of the data field in a list"""
        
        nodes = []
        curr = self.head
        
        while curr:
            nodes.append(repr(curr))
            curr = curr.nextval
            
        return '[' + '->'.join(nodes) + ']'
    
    def prepend(self, dataval):
        
        """Insert a new element at the beginning of the list."""
        
        self.head = Node(dataval=dataval, nextval=self.head)
        
    def append(self, dataval):
        
        """Insert a new element at the end of the list."""
        
        if not self.head:
            self.head = Node(dataval=dataval)
            return
        
        curr = self.head
        
        while curr.nextval:
            curr = curr.nextval
            
        curr.nextval = Node(dataval=dataval)
```

The code works, I just don't understand quite how it works. It's from an online course about data structures.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you, what do you mean "while invoking other methods"? `__repr__` gets called in specific contexts or when you call it directly or indirectly through the `repr(obj)` built-in function.

Comment: " It looks to me like the list "nodes" would get initialized over and over again. Thanks!" Ah, so, `repr(curr)` *doesn't call `LinkedList.__repr__`, it calls `Node.__repr__`. There is no recursion here, if that is what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Inside the LinkedList's `__repr__` you create a new local `nodes` list, you call the `__repr__` of all of the nodes by passing on their `nextval` attribute and add their string representation to the list, and then concatenate the list together using `'->'.join()`.

You can visualize it using [python tutor](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=class%20Node%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%22%22%22A%20node%20in%20a%20singly-linked%20list%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self,%20dataval%3DNone,%20nextval%3DNone%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.dataval%20%3D%20dataval%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.nextval%20%3D%20nextval%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__repr__%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20repr%28self.dataval%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Aclass%20LinkedList%3A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__init__%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Creating%20a%20new%20singly-linked%20list.%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.head%20%3D%20None%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20def%20__repr__%28self%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Creating%20a%20string%20representation%20of%20the%20data%20field%20in%20a%20list%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20curr%20%3D%20self.head%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20while%20curr%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nodes.append%28repr%28curr%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20curr%20%3D%20curr.nextval%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%27%5B%27%20%2B%20%27-%3E%27.join%28nodes%29%20%2B%20%27%5D%27%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20def%20prepend%28self,%20dataval%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Insert%20a%20new%20element%20at%20the%20beginning%20of%20the%20list.%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.head%20%3D%20Node%28dataval%3Ddataval,%20nextval%3Dself.head%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20def%20append%28self,%20dataval%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%22%22Insert%20a%20new%20element%20at%20the%20end%20of%20the%20list.%22%22%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20not%20self.head%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self.head%20%3D%20Node%28dataval%3Ddataval%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20curr%20%3D%20self.head%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20while%20curr.nextval%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20curr%20%3D%20curr.nextval%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20curr.nextval%20%3D%20Node%28dataval%3Ddataval%29%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0Al%20%3D%20LinkedList%28%29%0Al.append%281%29%0Al.append%282%29%0Al.append%283%29%0Aprint%28repr%28l%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=40&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false) starting from step 41.

Comment: Thank you @Bharel, I didn't realize that the output was being generated at the end once you call repr(l).  I though it was adding to the `nodes` list with each l.append().

Comment: Interestingly, in my Jupyter notebook I only have to type the name of the instance (`l` in this case).  Apparently behind the scenes it is calling `repr` when I do that.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confused about the call to `append` in `__repr__`: that is *not* a call to the `append` method in your class. It is calling [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) on a native `list` type. The two methods happen to have the same name, and I guess that's where the mixup comes from.

The `__repr__` method creates a `list` (not a `LinkedList`) and populates it with the string representations of the nodes in the linked list. Then it joins those strings to one string and returns it. During this process no other method of the `LinkedList` class is called.

Answer (score 1):

`__repr__` isn't called in the `prepend` and `append` routines. The `nodes` list in `LinkedList.__rep__` is only there temporarily to hold the nodes while its return value is built. In fact, your classes don't use `list` to hold nodes at all. `LinkedList` has a reference to the first `Node` in `head` and each `Node` has a reference to the next node in `nextval`.

Comment: I see what's happening now.  I appreciate it @tdelaney!